# Is there any way to display websites or html/javascript in a widget in tkinter?

Tags: javascript, python, html, tkinter

I'm trying to build a simple `tkinter` application that can easily display half complex websites. What I mean with half complex is the usage of JavaScript and html.

I did try using packages like `tkinterweb`, `tkhtmlview`, `tkinterhtml`, `pywebkit` but all of them failed to either work properly with tkinter or could just load simple pages like *https://**google**.com*

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

leftside = Frame(window, width=400, height=500, bg="black")
leftside.grid(column=0, row=0)

#rightside = insert browser/html here
#rightside.grid(column=1, row=0)

window.title("Displaying a Website")
window.geometry("800x500")
window.mainloop()
```